# How to reset a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm trying to do this (using a custom class, and STL shared_ptr from `#include <memory>`):

```
shared_ptr<Label> BufLbl;

BufLbl = allocate_shared<Label>(Label());
BufLbl->YCoord = 3;
BufLbl->XCoord = 2; 
BufLbl->Width = 5;
BufLbl->Data = "Day 1";
Screen.Controls.push_back(BufLbl);

BufLbl = allocate_shared<Label>(Label());
BufLbl->YCoord = 4;
BufLbl->XCoord = 6; 
BufLbl->Width = 1;
BufLbl->Data = "2";
Screen.Controls.push_back(BufLbl);

<repeat>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error C2903: 'rebind' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Somehow I'm thinking `Label` doesn't fulfill the Allocator concept... Why are you using `allocate_shared` instead of `make_shared`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing `allocate_shared`, which isn't what you think.

What you need is `make_shared`, like this:

```
BufLbl = std::make_shared<Label>();
```

Comment: Looks like this worked. But can you point me to a usage guide for shared_ptr and its associated functions? I felt pretty proud of myself for figuring out that allocate_shared even existed.

Comment: Try [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). Or browse SO. There've been tons of very useful posts about `shared_ptr`. Or watch STL's [*Advanced STL #1*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-1-of-n).